# Will I be allowed to cycle from Port Said to Hurgada, in Egypt?

Tags: bicycles, egypt

I looking for someone with recent (2017 / 2018) experience cycling in Egypt.

1. Will the police prevent me due to security concerns?
2. Are cyclist not allowed on parts of the route, e.g. because some parts are considered highway and off-limits to cyclists?

[image]

---

**Update**

I asked the same question on [Lonely Planet Thorn Tree](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/africa/egypt/will-i-be-allowed-to-cycle-from-port-said-to-hurgada-and-then-across-to-luxor). I was refered to [www.crazyguyonabike.com](http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/doc/locales/?locale_id=64&doctype=journal) which has reports / journals from cyclists who have been to that area.

Comment: It's important to note that Google Maps is refusing to provide cycling directions for this city pair.

Comment: Given @MichaelHampton's point I would advise the OP to split the route and try to track down where the route breaks between the cities

Comment: A quick look on Google maps shows a lot of this route is toll highway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

End of  December 2018 I cycled from Port Said, to Ismailia, to Suez city, to Porto Sokhna, to Zaafarana (on the red sea 254 km north west of Hurghada) without any issues and no police escort.

Then, at 11am on 30 December 2018 at the check point south out of Zaafarana, the police said I was not allowed to cycle further south, down to Hurghada. I was also told that I was not allowed to cycle from Hurghada to Qena. Nor was I allowed to cycle from Zaafarana to Beni Suef ( so as to continue south down the Nile). All these routes are in the Red Sea province (protectorate?) of Egypt.

The police at the check point told me this and at my insistence they let me speak telephonically to the "security manager" in Hurghada who confirmed that cyclists are not allowed to cycle that route.

The options the police gave me

1. cycle back the way I came, i.e. north along the Red Sea to Suez
2. Take a bus from the check point at Zaafarana back to Cairo.
3. Take a bus from the check point to Hurghada.

The police were very polite and patient with me (they offered tea, coffee, food, a chair in the shade). I used google translate ( english - arabic) a lot.

(The police also told me that the only way to get permission to cycle the route was to get my consulate to get me security clearance. But because of my lack of Arabic I am not sure I understood this security clearance.)

(I was not stopped at the toll near Port Said.)